# Need to add method parameters with each iteration in java

Tags: java, mongodb, group-by, project, aggregates

In the below piece of code I need to add arguments inside fields method with each iteration.

```
  for(int i=0; i< groups.size(); i++) {
            project = Aggregates.project(fields(computed(groups.get(i), "$_id." + groups.get(i)), include("productId", "productName")));
        }
```

i.e., in the second iteration the line of code inside for loop should be the one as below.

```
for(int i=0; i< groups.size(); i++) {
            project = Aggregates.project(fields(computed(groups.get(i), "$_id." + groups.get(i)), computed(groups.get(i+1), "$_id." + groups.get(i+1)), include("productId", "productName")));
        }
```

Can someone help on this?

Comment: `i+1` may be `>= groups.size()`

Comment: What's the signature of `fields()`?

Comment: Its a method in Projections class.

public static Bson fields(final Bson... projections) {
        return fields(asList(projections));
    }

Comment: Create a `List<Bson>` and use the version of `fields()` which takes a list, instead of the varargs signature.